# Testing with Clock

Tags: spring-test, spring-test-mvc

Is it possible to have an instance of Clock being configured per test class?

Problem is that Clock of the current test is being overwritten by the configuration of another test.

I'm configuring my tests like bellow:

```
public class ClockTestCase extends AbstractTestCase {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        Clock fixedClock() {
            LocalDateTime fixed = ...
            return Clock.fixed(fixed.toInstant(ZoneOffset.of(AMERICA_SAO_PAULO_OFFSET_ID)), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // Act and Assert
        this.mvc()
            .perform(put(MY_URL, 1))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```